# How to cancel pendingIntent AlarmManager after alarm fire 1 time

Tags: java, android

here is my code to set alarm to my notes list and i call it at getData method.

the problem is i calls every time the app started or update any data and if current time right then was the same as the time set in alarm it will show a notification again

i want to ask how to set the alarm Manager only fire one time but repeat the following day or week if i keep

```
public void SetAlarm(int d, int h, int m, int id, String note){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, d);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        startAlarm(calendar, id, note);
    }
    private void startAlarm(Calendar c, int id, String note){
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("note", note);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), id, intent, 0);
        if (c.before(Calendar.getInstance())){
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

```
    public void getActiveNote(){
        for (int i = 0; i < notesList.size(); i++){
            Frag2_Notes note = notesList.get(i);
            if (note.getRepeat() == 0){
                if (note.getMon() == 1){
                    SetAlarm(2, note.getTime_of_day(), note.getNote_minute(), note.getnID(), note.getnName());
                }else if (note.getTue() == 1){
                    SetAlarm(3, note.getTime_of_day(), note.getNote_minute(), note.getnID(), note.getnName());
                }else if (note.getWed() == 1){
                    SetAlarm(4, note.getTime_of_day(), note.getNote_minute(), note.getnID(), note.getnName());
                }else if (note.getThu() == 1){
                    SetAlarm(5, note.getTime_of_day(), note.getNote_minute(), note.getnID(), note.getnName());
                }else if (note.getFri() == 1){
                    SetAlarm(6, note.getTime_of_day(), note.getNote_minute(), note.getnID(), note.getnName());
                }else if (note.getSat() == 1){
                    SetAlarm(7, note.getTime_of_day(), note.getNote_minute(), note.getnID(), note.getnName());
                }else if (note.getSun() == 1){
                    SetAlarm(1, note.getTime_of_day(), note.getNote_minute(), note.getnID(), note.getnName());
                }
            }else if (note.getRepeat() == 1){
                SetAlarm(2, note.getTime_of_day(), note.getNote_minute(), note.getnID(), note.getnName());
                SetAlarm(3, note.getTime_of_day(), note.getNote_minute(), note.getnID(), note.getnName());
                SetAlarm(4, note.getTime_of_day(), note.getNote_minute(), note.getnID(), note.getnName());
                SetAlarm(5, note.getTime_of_day(), note.getNote_minute(), note.getnID(), note.getnName());
                SetAlarm(6, note.getTime_of_day(), note.getNote_minute(), note.getnID(), note.getnName());
                SetAlarm(7, note.getTime_of_day(), note.getNote_minute(), note.getnID(), note.getnName());
                SetAlarm(1, note.getTime_of_day(), note.getNote_minute(), note.getnID(), note.getnName());
            }
        }
    }
```

```
private void GetData(){
        notesList.clear();
        notesList.addAll(database.getAllNote());
        getActiveNote();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```